# How to understand which parse cloud function is calling beforeSave function?

Tags: parse-platform

I have functions like these which all save stuff at the same class in parse database.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("add_comment", function(request,response){
 ...
});
Parse.Cloud.define("edit_comment", function(request,response){
 ...
});
Parse.Cloud.define("like_comment", function(request,response){
 ...
});
```

Is there an effective way I can seperate all of these fuctions in beforeSave?

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Comments", function(request, response) {
    //Should only work for "add_comment" and not for the other ones.
});
```

Comment: Then you probably want to check if object is new via `request.object.isNew()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I also want to call that function in cases where the object is not new, i.e. "like_comment"

Comment: What I mean is you basically check if the object is new in `beforeSave`, if it is handle `add_comment`, else `handle_edit/like_comment`;

Comment: @eth3lbert that worked in beforeSave but doesnt work in afterSave.. what is the solution for that?

Comment: Try `request.object.existed()`